# Expo google sign in redirect always on app login on Standelone app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-signin

I hope you are doing well.
I have a problem when I connect with google on the emulator with android.
If I go through Expo Go on either Android or Ios, it works fine. But when I build my apk, and I install it on the emulator it sends me back to the same login page without redirecting me to the application.

Do you have an idea of the origin of the problem?

My google login function :

```
            try {
            const result = await promptAsync();
            if (result.type === "success") {
                /* `accessToken` is now valid and can be used to get data from the Google API with HTTP requests */
                const { id_token } = result.params;

                const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

                const credential =
                    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
                
                auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .then((res) => {
                        const user = res.additionalUserInfo.profile;
                        let action = addUserOnFirestore(
                            res.user?.uid,
                            user.email,
                            user.given_name,
                            user.family_name,
                            user.picture,
                            res
                        );
                        
                        setIsLoading(true);
                        try {
                            dispatch(action);
                        } catch (err) {
                            setError(err.message);
                        }
                        setIsLoading(false);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("firebase cred err:", error);
                    });
            } else {
                console.log("cancelled");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("general error : ", e);
            return { error: true };
        }
    }
```

And the properties define :

```
        const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
        clientId: "XXXX",
        iosClientId: "XXX",
        androidClientId: "XXX",
        androidStandaloneAppClientId: "XXX",
        redirectUri: Platform.select({
            // iOS handles redirectUri perfectly fine on it's own
            ios: undefined,
            // Due to Expo's bug, we need to manually encode the redirectUri
            // https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12044
            android: makeRedirectUri({
                // intent filter set up in app.config.js
                // must be the same as "package name" in Google Cloud Console
                native: 'packagename://oauthredirect',
            }),
        })
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: OK it's good now. Any suggestion about the source of error ?